# Model is not being populated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-framework-version

post.cshtml

```
@model NameSpace.Models.PostNewsModel
<style>
    .col-centered {
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
<br />
<br />

@using (Html.BeginForm(
    "Post",
    "Page",
    new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl },
    FormMethod.Post,
    new
    {
        @class = "form-box",
        role = "form",
        id = "edit",
        enctype = "multipart/form-data"
    }))
{

    <div style="color:red">
        <span>
            <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostTitle, "")</p>
            <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "")</p>
            <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostImage, "")</p>

            <p>@ViewBag.Message</p>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">
        <label class="label" style="display: inline-block">Title</label>
        <input required="" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Title of blog post" aria-describedby="desc_title" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Title field is required." id="PostTitle">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">
        <label class="label" style="display: inline-block">Image</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control mb-3" id="PostImage" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">
        <textarea id="Content" class="form-control mb-4" rows="20" aria-label="Content"></textarea>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-centered">
        <input type="submit" value="Post News"/>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
}

<script src="~/plugins/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/admin.js" async></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/admin.scss" />
```

PageController.cs post

```
[Route("post")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult post(PostNewsModel model, HttpPostedFileBase imageFile)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (imageFile != null && imageFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                var rnd = "0123456789qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm".Scramble().Substring(0, 10);
                var random = Md5Hash.Hash(rnd);
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/img/News"), Path.GetFileName(random + imageFile.FileName));
                imageFile.SaveAs(path);
                ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "ERROR:" + ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "You have not specified a file.";
        }
        if (PostNews(model, imageFile))
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Successfully posted";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "It's not valid for some reason.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
            .Where(y => y.Count > 0)
            .ToList();
        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(model.PostTitle);
        Console.WriteLine(model.Content);
        Console.WriteLine(model.PostImage);
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

PostNewsModel.cs

```
public class PostNewsModel
{
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }

    public string PostImage { get; set; }

    public string PostDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    public string PostViews { get; set; } = "1";
}
```

When I fill the form and press "Post News", it reaches to post function in Controller but passes an empty model (all fields are null). I tried changing fields, ids, names and what not but couldn't solve it. Also looked around the internet and even though found cases where people had this issue, none of the solutions that are provided worked for me. Sorry for the newbie question as I'm pretty new to the world of ASP.

Update:

Solved the issue. Problem was that I used `id = "edit"` in my form. I don't know how and why it didn't work though.

Comment: please add attribute  'name = "<column name>"'
it will works.

Comment: @chandukomati hey, thanks for the answer. I tried adding name before but when I add name, I get 500 error and it doesn't reach to post function in Controller.

Comment: Not sure, but it looks like `PostImage` in model should be of type `HttpPostedFileBase` and no second argument in controller method `post` is not needed

Comment: @Quercus hey, thanks for looking into it. It's a good idea, changed it the way you suggested.